# Why has this user lost all of his reputation on SO?

Tags: bug, reputation, users

I've seen a user on Stack Overflow who lost all of his reputation, meaning he now has 1 reputation, when he had tens of thousands, and also multiple gold (JavaScript, jQuery, PHP, HTML, etc.), silver and bronze badges. I can post the link to his profile if needed.

How can something like this happen?

Comment: His account is suspended, see the faq.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks for the quick response. Any reason why would that happen?

Comment: Nevermind, I just found this https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/

Comment: @Ionut There can be many reasons. SE usually doesn't tell us why someone is suspended - it's none of our business. That way, after a user's suspension is over, the user can continue with a clean slate. Meanwhile - you will usually get a warning before you get a suspension.

Comment: @S.L.Barth, thanks for clearing that out. Appreciate it.

Comment: By the way, his reputation is not lost, it shows as 1 during the time of his suspension. When the suspension is over, all his rep will show back in his profile.

Comment: I already understood that once I've found the link posted on my above comment. Thanks.